# Calculate for k?

Tags: equation-solving

The mathematical question is as follows:

> Calculate the value of k for which 2x^2 + 4x - k = 0 has equal roots.

*My working solves it to equal -2, but if we then put this back into the formula this is, of course, impossible. I use the discriminate of the quadratic equation, b^2-4ac.*

Comment: Wrong forum. You want http://math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you.

Comment: If you're not going to be using *Mathematica*, please ask at [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) the next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this quite easily using Mathematica:

```
r = Roots[2 x^2 + 4 x - k == 0, x];
Solve[r[[1, 2]] == r[[2, 2]], k]

{{k -> -2}}
```

Check:

```
Roots[2 x^2 + 4 x + 2 == 0, x]
x == -1 || x == -1
```